# Why is my img flowing out of my div in dev tool?

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming, learning HTML CSS. I have a flowing img out of my div which is the .team-main. It affects the width of the other sections. How can I stop this? so my sections do not cover the page horizontally because of this. Can somebody help me fix this please?

this is the ss of the background color: [Not fitting background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lnf1.png)

```css
#team {
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.team-main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 800px;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.team-title h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.team-title p {
  color: #6c757d;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: larger;
  text-align: center;
}

.team-member p {
  color: #6c757d;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0.4rem 0 1rem;
}

.team-members {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3rem 5rem 5rem;
}

.team-members-middle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  color: #6c757d;
}

.team-member {
  width: 100%;
}

.team-member img {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 1rem 7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #d4d5d7;
}

.team-member .member {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #111212;
}

.team-member .member i {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="team">
      <div class="team-main">
        <div class="team-title">
          <h1 id="team">OUR AMAZING TEAM</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="team-members">
          <div class="team-member">
            <img src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/assets/img/team/1.jpg" alt="" />
            <h2>Parveen Anand</h2>
            <p>Lead Designer</p>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></div>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a></div>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a> </div>
         

          </div>

          <div class="team-member">
            <img src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/assets/img/team/2.jpg" alt="" />
            <h2>Diana Petersen</h2>
            <p>Lead Marketer</p>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></div>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a></div>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a> </div>
           </div>

          <div class="team-member">
            <img src="https://startbootstrap.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/assets/img/team/3.jpg" alt="" />
            <h2>Larry Parker</h2>
            <p>Lead Developer</p>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></div>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i></a></div>
            <div class="member"><a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a> </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <p class="team-members-middle">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut eaque,
          laboriosam veritatis, quos non quis ad perspiciatis, totam corporis
          ea, alias ut unde.
        </p>
      </div>
```

https://codepen.io/mizginyildirak/pen/ZERzOVx

Comment: The images don't show on the codepen :(. Maybe you can use some generic online images to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: okay will fix it right away.

Now it is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will keep it simple, **whenever you decide to use `flex` attribute on a row avoid using `width` attribute on that element**, especially the `100%` value. Because **flex items by default are set to `flex-shrink: 1`, which means they are permitted to shrink in order to fit inside the container**. Therefore by specifying the `width: 100%;` attribute for the container, you will break this rule.

So removing `width: 100%;` from `team-members` class will fix the problem.

```css
...
.team-members {
  width: 100%; /* remove this line */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3rem 5rem 5rem;
}
...
```

### Update

First off, you also need to remove `width: 100%;` from the `#team` element too, then instead of giving each image within the flex container the margin (`margin: 1rem 7rem`), give its parent the [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) property. **Keep in mind the margins will make the container box larger therefore the contents will overflow from the main targeting theme.**

Change your CSS code like this and you will fix the issue.

```css
...
.team-members {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 7rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3rem 5rem 5rem;
}
...
.team-member img {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #d4d5d7;
}
...
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/wvXwzjy

Comment: Thank you but it didn't fix unfortunately :( I have linked an image which is an unfit background color. Can you check it please? It doesn't fit

Comment: @MizginYıldırak Update your CodePen to let us check what's happening. Also, keep in mind you need to define certain breakpoints with [`media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) properties and make your row element wrap (like `flex-wrap: wrap`) or create another design for it. This code alone won't be fit on every screen.

Comment: It is updated. I know but it starts flowing from the very beginning

Comment: @MizginYıldırak There is still a `width: 100%;` on `.teams-members`, remove it and you are good to go. [Here it is](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/wvXwzjy).

Comment: okay but I still have the background color problem that doesn't fit my div. It is not fixed

Comment: Yesss it worked. But why did it work tho? Thank you so much for your help btw

Comment: @MizginYıldırak I will refer you to my explanation about how the `width` and `margin` will affect the the `flex` element and also the [box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) element. Please read the reasons carefully in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of two things:

1. The images have defined `height` and `width` values, and so can't scale responsively
2. There is a huge amount of `margin` on a couple elements that cause the images to overflow their container

Ultimately, the issue is just that the flexed elements are too wide to reside entirely inside the container, so it overflows. It's a classic CSS problem.

**How to fix**

For #1, simply remove the `height` and `width` values, and instead use:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

For #2, reduce the margins at small screen resolutions with breakpoints.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex-item {
    margin: 3rem 5rem 5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
    <p>Name 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
    <p>Name 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
    <p>Name 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```